# Extracting Point estimates and 95% CIs section of epi.tests output

Tags: r, dataframe

I am curious about obtaining the "Point estimates and 95% CIs" section from the `epi.tests` function in the [epir](/questions/tagged/epir) package for [r](/questions/tagged/r) as a `data.frame`.

```
library(epiR)
#> Loading required package: survival
#> Package epiR 2.0.61 is loaded
#> Type help(epi.about) for summary information
#> Type browseVignettes(package = 'epiR') to learn how to use epiR for applied epidemiological analyses
#> 

dat.v01    <- c(670,202,74,640)
rval.tes01 <- epi.tests(dat.v01)
rval.tes01
#>           Outcome +    Outcome -      Total
#> Test +          670          202        872
#> Test -           74          640        714
#> Total           744          842       1586
#> 
#> Point estimates and 95% CIs:
#> --------------------------------------------------------------
#> Apparent prevalence *                  0.55 (0.52, 0.57)
#> True prevalence *                      0.47 (0.44, 0.49)
#> Sensitivity *                          0.90 (0.88, 0.92)
#> Specificity *                          0.76 (0.73, 0.79)
#> Positive predictive value *            0.77 (0.74, 0.80)
#> Negative predictive value *            0.90 (0.87, 0.92)
#> Positive likelihood ratio              3.75 (3.32, 4.24)
#> Negative likelihood ratio              0.13 (0.11, 0.16)
#> False T+ proportion for true D- *      0.24 (0.21, 0.27)
#> False T- proportion for true D+ *      0.10 (0.08, 0.12)
#> False T+ proportion for T+ *           0.23 (0.20, 0.26)
#> False T- proportion for T- *           0.10 (0.08, 0.13)
#> Correctly classified proportion *      0.83 (0.81, 0.84)
#> --------------------------------------------------------------
#> * Exact CIs

class(rval.tes01)
#> [1] "epi.tests"
unclass(rval.tes01)
#> $detail
#>    statistic         est       lower      upper
#> 1         ap  0.54981084  0.52493735  0.5744996
#> 2         tp  0.46910467  0.44430554  0.4940184
#> 3         se  0.90053763  0.87674618  0.9210923
#> 4         sp  0.76009501  0.72977646  0.7885803
#> 5    diag.ac  0.82597730  0.80640489  0.8443346
#> 6    diag.or 28.68611185 21.51819166 38.2417364
#> 7       nndx  1.51370055  1.40910043  1.6487431
#> 8     youden  0.66063265  0.60652264  0.7096726
#> 9     pv.pos  0.76834862  0.73889263  0.7959784
#> 10    pv.neg  0.89635854  0.87163929  0.9177402
#> 11    lr.pos  3.75372618  3.32068844  4.2432346
#> 12    lr.neg  0.13085517  0.10506432  0.1629771
#> 13    p.rout  0.45018916  0.42550037  0.4750627
#> 14     p.rin  0.54981084  0.52493735  0.5744996
#> 15    p.tpdn  0.23990499  0.21141968  0.2702235
#> 16    p.tndp  0.09946237  0.07890770  0.1232538
#> 17    p.dntp  0.23165138  0.20402157  0.2611074
#> 18    p.dptn  0.10364146  0.08225983  0.1283607
#> 
#> $tab
#>           Outcome +    Outcome -      Total
#> Test +          670          202        872
#> Test -           74          640        714
#> Total           744          842       1586
#> 
#> $method
#> [1] "exact"
#> 
#> $digits
#> [1] 2
#> 
#> $conf.level
#> [1] 0.95

str(rval.tes01)
#> List of 5
#>  $ detail    :'data.frame':  18 obs. of  4 variables:
#>   ..$ statistic: chr [1:18] "ap" "tp" "se" "sp" ...
#>   ..$ est      : num [1:18] 0.55 0.469 0.901 0.76 0.826 ...
#>   ..$ lower    : num [1:18] 0.525 0.444 0.877 0.73 0.806 ...
#>   ..$ upper    : num [1:18] 0.574 0.494 0.921 0.789 0.844 ...
#>  $ tab       :'data.frame':  3 obs. of  3 variables:
#>   ..$    Outcome +: 'AsIs' chr [1:3] "670" " 74" "744"
#>   ..$    Outcome -: 'AsIs' chr [1:3] "202" "640" "842"
#>   ..$      Total  : 'AsIs' chr [1:3] " 872" " 714" "1586"
#>  $ method    : chr "exact"
#>  $ digits    : num 2
#>  $ conf.level: num 0.95
#>  - attr(*, "class")= chr "epi.tests"

rval.tes01$detail
#>    statistic         est       lower      upper
#> 1         ap  0.54981084  0.52493735  0.5744996
#> 2         tp  0.46910467  0.44430554  0.4940184
#> 3         se  0.90053763  0.87674618  0.9210923
#> 4         sp  0.76009501  0.72977646  0.7885803
#> 5    diag.ac  0.82597730  0.80640489  0.8443346
#> 6    diag.or 28.68611185 21.51819166 38.2417364
#> 7       nndx  1.51370055  1.40910043  1.6487431
#> 8     youden  0.66063265  0.60652264  0.7096726
#> 9     pv.pos  0.76834862  0.73889263  0.7959784
#> 10    pv.neg  0.89635854  0.87163929  0.9177402
#> 11    lr.pos  3.75372618  3.32068844  4.2432346
#> 12    lr.neg  0.13085517  0.10506432  0.1629771
#> 13    p.rout  0.45018916  0.42550037  0.4750627
#> 14     p.rin  0.54981084  0.52493735  0.5744996
#> 15    p.tpdn  0.23990499  0.21141968  0.2702235
#> 16    p.tndp  0.09946237  0.07890770  0.1232538
#> 17    p.dntp  0.23165138  0.20402157  0.2611074
#> 18    p.dptn  0.10364146  0.08225983  0.1283607
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse the printed summary info using `capture.output()`.

```
library(tidyverse)

dat.v01    <- c(670,202,74,640)
rval.tes01 <- epi.tests(dat.v01)
df <- capture.output(rval.tes01)
x <- df[c(6,8:20)] # extract lines with data.frame output
xc <- paste(x, collapse = "\n") # combine into a single character vector with new line
out <- readr::read_fwf(xc, readr::fwf_empty(xc), ) 
out <- as.data.frame(as.matrix(out, nrow = 14, ncol = 2))
out$X6 <- paste0(out$X4, out$X5)
out <- out[, -c(4,5)]
colnames(out) <- out[1, ]
out <- out[-1, ]
colnames(out)[2:4] <- c("", "statistic", "CI")
out[, 2] <- ifelse(is.na(out[, 2]), "", out[, 2])
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This gives the same output as `rval.tes01$detail`. But need the other part which contains complete names along with Point Estimates and CIs.

Comment: Updated answer using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39443324/r-function-that-parses-output-printed-to-console-and-returns-meaningful-object)